Implementing a PIN based Confirmation Mechanism for my mobile app
I am building an react native mobile app that lets user do certain kinds of transcations. The only allows users to logs in via compliant OpenID connect providers (Google/FB/etc.). The backend does not have it's own IdM.
I want to build a confirmation flow that requires the user to enter a PIN before they finalise a transaction. The PIN should be constant across devices (which means I need to store the PIN server side). If the user chose to toggle an option, they would not be required to enter the PIN again and could be replaced by biometric confirmation.
Question:
What kind of components do I need to build that facilitates the storage of this PIN and have it stored securely on the device?
How does the user reset this PIN in case they forget it?
It almost feels like deploying an IdM solution specifically for this, but having the user log in via google and the whole PIN approach seems that I need to wet my feet building another IdM of my own. Are there any standard open source/off-the-shelf tools I can use to do all of this stuff?
